ToolStripProfessionalRenderer to override appearance dynamically (C#, Winforms)
I tried searching but found nothing about this specific need. I'm handling the text color of my menu items with this code
    private class SkinRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
    {
        public SkinRenderer(MenuColorTable colorTable) : base(colorTable) => Console.WriteLine("test");
        protected override void OnRenderItemText(ToolStripItemTextRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            e.TextColor = Color.FromArgb(220, 220, 220);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Text, e.TextFont, e.TextRectangle, e.TextColor, e.TextFormat);
        }
    }

Aside mentioning that I don't actually know how to handle the first line inside this code (I only know it's necessary to handle a custom MenuColorTable but I don't understand why I must mandatorily state some code instruction), what I need to do mainly in this topic is setting the text color based on some conditions but I don't get how to do that. My first take is like, when I need to change that, I'll use another ToolStripProfessionalRenderer with a different text color but it seems a bit stupid to me. I mean, must I really do that? I'd rather set the text in some way like
e.TextColor = intVariable > 10 ? Color.Black : Color.White;

but it seems I cannot use this kind of statement because anything that's in the form cannot be used inside this method. Maybe it's something about how the classes are declared? I don't know if that's the case. I also tried passing some parameter to use but I didn't manage to do that, I'm also not finding so many clear instructions about how to pass parameters for classes (something like a parameter to use in Public Sub New() in VB.Net). What I have (showing only the structure for understanding purposes) is:
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private class SkinRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
    {
        override method
    }
}

So basically the condition to use for the text is inside the form but outside the class and I don't know how to do that. Also, but I think it's important to start understanding from this very step, if I can handle the text, I can handle dynamically also the other components of the menu. So, first, I'm focusing just on this basic task.
I remembered also this could be useful to read. I'm setting the renderer like this in the load event of the form:
menu.Renderer = new SkinRenderer(new MenuColorTable());

The color table is another class that I suppose is not needed to see for the text purpose.

This public SkinRenderer(...) { } in c# is Public Sub New() End Sub in vb.net and it's called Constructor by the way. You can add more constructors that take more parameters as you need and assign their values to local fields of same types. Then, use them to control the renderer. Also, you can expose public properties that a caller can get/set. In this case, keep the renderer instance in a private field or cast menu.Renderer to SkinRenderer to access its members.

Btw, you don't need to call TextRenderer.DrawText(... here. Set the e.TextColor and call the base method base.OnRenderItemText(e);.

The first comment goes quite beyond my notions for now, so I actually don't totally understand what you proposed to do. Could you be more explicit with a code example?

Thanks also for the input about the constructor, I tried some more tests and it seems I got to pass and use an attribute so I suppose I can start from there. It will be much more minimal to have only one class for both renderer and the colortable, instead of one for each skin!

The only thing it's not clear to me is I just added the parameter to the public SkinRenderer() and not to the base() so I don't quite understand what the : base(...) means nor why it's necessary to handle the ColorTable for that reason. I mean: in VB.Net I would have only a New(parameters) while here I have SkinRenderer(parameters) : base(parameter).

Your question is more about OOP to me. You must read about that to understand inheritance, polymorphism, ..etc before going any further. In vb.net, you must do the same by calling MyBase.New(someColorTable). In c# : base(someColorTable) { }. Why? Because the ColorTable property is read-only and the base class provides a special constructor to set it. See

Oh, I see! Thank you for now, interesting learning always something new!
